# sshtunnel timing out when used within a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pymongo, ssh-tunnel

I have an application that connects to a mongo database on aws through an SSH Tunnel. When I run the application outside a virtualenv it works just fine and is able to connect to the database but within a virtualenv I always get the following timeout error

```
db-url:27017: timed out,db-url:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61f46c0c4ce4a333018443c3, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('db-url', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('db-url: timed out')>, <ServerDescription ('db-url', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('db-url:27017: timed out')>]>
```

I have installed the same package versions (including dependencies) for sshtunnel in the virtualenv and outside it but the same error still occurs.

Just for reference, this is the code I'm using to create the SSH Tunnel

```
# Create the tunnel
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (SSH_HOST, SSH_PORT),
    ssh_username= SSH_USER,
    ssh_pkey=SSH_PEM,
    remote_bind_address=(DB_HOST, DB_SOURCE_PORT),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', DB_TARGET_PORT)
)
# Start the tunnel
server.start()
```

I then connect to mongoDB like so

```
client = MongoClient(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=DB_TARGET_PORT,
        username=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASSWORD,
        retryWrites=False
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you are using `conda`, did you create  your virtual environment with `conda`?

Comment: No I made it normally

Comment: Do they both have the same URI connection string?  What is it?

Comment: I am not using a URI to connect. I edited the question and added the connection method

Comment: Which OS is this on?  In your normal/working environment, are any of the python environment variables set?  How do these change in your virtual environment?  Any "surprise" consequences due to the PATH environment variable change in the virtual environment?

Comment: try it with IP instead of name.

Comment: @rickhg12hs No there should not be any such consequences. And yes all the variables are set properly

Comment: @Gábor Thank you, that worked somehow. However I do not understand the difference between using IP and using the name.

Comment: @Gábor Interesting!  How does the virtual environment lose DNS capability?

Comment: @varunbheemaiah may it use different path as root and there is no or there is a different resolv.conf in there.